# Ajax post parameters ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Hello guys i have the next ajax call for login. I serialize the form and send the data to server and return redirect url link. My problem is that my url after post is like

```
http://localhost:50802/?username=&password= and not http://localhost:50802/Home

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login/Login",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: loginJson,
                cache: true,
                async: false,
                complete: function (result) {
                    alert(result.link);
                    window.location.replace = "/Home/Index";
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#username").val("");
                    $("#password").val("");
                    alert("Wrong Username or Password!");
                }
            }); //end ajax call
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wrote this `$.ajax` call in the `.click` event of a submit button or in the `.submit` event of a form without canceling the default action by returning false from the callback or by calling `preventDefault` on the argument. Here's how your code should look like:

```
$('#id_of_your_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventdefault(); // <-- That's what I am talking about and what you forgot

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login/Login",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: loginJson,
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        complete: function (result) {
            window.location.replace = "/Home/Index";
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#username").val("");
            $("#password").val("");
            alert("Wrong Username or Password!");
        }
    }); //end ajax call
});
```

Also `async: false,`????? You know what this does, do you? That's not AJAX. That's a blocking synchronous call to your webserver during which the client browser would be frozen like during the Ice Age 2 ruining all user experience.

Comment: I put e.preventdefault() it does not solve the problem parameters are still present and i can't get the redirect to work. The funny thing is that when i use debug in firebug it does redirect after i pass the ajax post xD

Comment: Maybe you have some javascript errors? can you seem them in the console?

Comment: I don't see any of them in the console.What i can see is that it does alert me on success function but it does not change the url like success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.link);
                    window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
                } and when i debug it it does trigger success function and redirect works.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false at the end of your submit function

```
$('#id_of_your_form').submit(function(e) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Login/Login",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: loginJson,
    cache: true,
    async: false,
    complete: function (result) {
        window.location = "/Home/Index";
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#username").val("");
        $("#password").val("");
        alert("Wrong Username or Password!");
    }
}); //end ajax call
return false; });
```

Another option would of course be to return the correct redirectlink from the controller instead of overriding it in the java script.